# LabelControl text length in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows

**LabelControl** in my form takes its **Text** property value dynamically.Text Value being long,half of the text gets overlapped by other controls or due to restriction in parent control size.I tried

> **AutoSize property**

,but it autosizes only in one fixed direction,either vertical or horizontal.I have also tried

> **SetPreferedSize(New Size(50,50))**

,but that is not working for me,can anybody show me a way how can I re-size my label-control to occupy a  *fixed rectangular size portion*?

Comment: In what mean you are asking for ?? Size of font? Or sozr of number of characters???

Comment: size in the sense of accomodating the whole text value with default size,you can take it as number of characters.

Comment: thats called Length...

Comment: Yes thanks, my question is the same.

Comment: Buy yes the question is on,yet not found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set following properties of Control:

WordWrap = Wrap

AutoSizeMode= None

VAlignment = Top

Width = 100

Height = 100

Or you can refer example link below:

[Devexpress Example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q309579)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a maximum width/height for a auto-sized label:

*Maximum width of 40px:*

```
Me.Label1.MaximumSize = New Size(40, 0)
```

*Maximum height of 40px:*

```
Me.Label1.MaximumSize = New Size(0, 40)
```

Comment: Thanks,but it is not working for me, I need my text to fill in vertically till the size specified and then to resume back to next line that is horizontally till its maximum size.

Comment: @Kbhatt Sorry, but I'm lost. You might want to append an image displaying what you want to achieve.